# How to Update an Excel Reader without using an openfiledialog C#

Tags: c#, excel, openfiledialog, exceldatareader

I've probably worded the question wrongly but it is easier to explain.

Basically on my form I have a button where if you click it, it opens up an OpenFileDialog search box and you are able to open an excel file and it gets displayed on various datagridview boxes in the form. And then you can input data into the excel worksheets. However because i'm a novice programmer, I can only update those datagridview's by clicked the button again and going through the OpenFileDialog again.

Here is the code I use to initially read the excel worksheets.

```
private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
            reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            result = reader.AsDataSet();

            cboSheet.Items.Clear();
            cboSheet_mirror.Items.Clear();
            resultSheet.Items.Clear();

            foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in result.Tables)
            {
                cboSheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                cboSheet_mirror.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                resultSheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
(...)
```

The cboSheet and resultSheets aren't relevant they are just what I use to navigate the different worksheets.

What I want to do is create a method where it updates the datagridview's with the edited excel worksheet but without the user having to go through the OpenFileDialog process every time, the program just knows the path to the excel file.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach to just remembering the file path would be to save it inside a class member after the user successfully selects a file:

```
string currentFilePath {get;set;} //Class member that will hold the path

private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.currentFilePath = ofd.FullName; //remember the path here

            (...)
```

Then in any other method or event handler inside your class you can read that path and open the excel file again without the need of another file selection process:

```
private void someOtherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     //read the file from the remembered path
     FileStream fs = File.Open(this.currentFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
     (...)
```

For more information about this topic I'd recommend reading some articles (like [this one](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1609145&seqNum=4)) about `Variable scopes`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a TextBox -e.g. ExcelFileTextBox- where you browse for your Excel file that after checking for `DialogResult.OK` set its `Text` property, This will also inform user about Excel path and filename.
You should move your Excel reading data to a - private - method instead, something like this:

```
private void ReadExcelData(string filename)
{
    FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
    result = reader.AsDataSet();

    cboSheet.Items.Clear();
    cboSheet_mirror.Items.Clear();
    resultSheet.Items.Clear();

    foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in result.Tables)
    {
        cboSheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
        cboSheet_mirror.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
        resultSheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

And your browse button code will become:

```
private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ExcelFileTextBox.Text = ofd.FileName;
            ReadExcelData(ofd.FileName);
         }
    }
}
```

Then add a refresh button that it also calls `ReadExcelData` like this:

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReadExcelData(ExcelFileTextBox.Text);
}
```

HTH